# NSNotification Called, but label will not update

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I have the following code called with `NSNotification` center, i know its being called because the array is appearing in the `NSLog`, but my label `chipCount` is not updating with the new value. Is there perhaps a method I applied wrong when extracting the string from the array?

```
-(NSString *) dataFilePath {
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Chips.plist"];
}

-(void)readPlist {
    [self dataFilePath];
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        chipArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSLog(@"%@\n", chipArray);
        NSLog(@"%@\n", filePath);

        NSString *chipcountString = [chipArray objectAtIndex:0];
        chipsFloat = [chipcountString intValue];
        chipCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", chipsFloat];
        //[arrayForPlist release];
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, its in my header as    IBOutlet UILabel *chipCount;

Comment: If you're not seeing anything in the label I'd recommend just trying to set it to a constant string value if you haven't already. That would at least rule out that your label is not connected right.

Comment: Make sure you are in the main thread! The ui may only be changed there. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004589/nsnotificationcenter-do-objects-receive-notifications-on-the-same-thread-they-a) for more information.

Comment: Try to `NSLog(@"loaded: %@, converted to: %i", chipcountString, chipsFloat)` at the end of this method and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: Its connected properly, It is a child view which gets the chip count originally from a parent view, but then the child view opens up another view which edits the value and tries to reset the value in the view with the new value

Comment: In the readPlist method can you do chipCount.text = @"Test"; and see a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a multithread problem. Update UI must in the main thread. Maybe `readPlist` is
executed in another thread.

Try this code below, maybe it can help you:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(theProcess:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; 

- (void) theProcess:(id)sender
{

    ....

    chipCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", chipsFloat];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assusming that chipcount is a UILabel.. is it possible that you need to tell it to refresh the label?

```
[chipcount setNeedsDisplay];
```

Just an idea.